# Move files from a list/array to a destination folder in Perl

Tags: perl

With **Perl** code

```
use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->mtime('<=' . (time() - 3600))
                            ->in("/source/directory/path");
```

I got a list of files in my source directory that were not modified for at least one hour.

What is the easiest way to move such files to a destination folder? **Error handling is** also **important.**

Do I have to use loop to move those files one by one, or is there some nice elegant and safe way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

*Working solution:*

```
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Copy;

my @files = File::Find::Rule
              ->file()
              ->mtime('<=' . (time() - 3600))
              ->exec( sub { 
                            my $r = move($_[2], "/destination/directory/path");
                            print STDERR "$_[2]\t$!\n" if !$r;
                            $r
                          }
                    )
              ->in("/source/directory/path");
```

Comment: You can use `warn` in place of `print STDERR`

Comment: This works only if the directory structure is flat or you want the destination directory to be flat. Otherwise you have to make sure that subdirectories are created in the destination first, e.g. using `mkpath` from `File::Path`.